# VB.NET - Hex Viewing

Tags: vb.net, view, hex

I'd like some help with my project, it's all educational related. 
The idea is, creating a hex viewer/editor, exactly like tools such Hex Workshop, HxD.

I've found this piece of code, it gave me the address but I also need to get the ASCII strings.

Here's the code I found

```
control.Text = String.Join(" ", IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OFD.FileName).Select(Function(b) b.ToString("X2")).ToArray())
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does it do, what does it not do ?

Comment: My code or asking what do I want the tool to perform?

Comment: It needs more detail.  It would help if you would explain your requirements much better, instead of naming apps that you want to duplicate.  Ideally you need to ask one question at a time about your next problem.

Comment: That code probably does exactly what you want.  It does not give you the address of anything, but converts the bytes read to hex strings.  if you *also* want the original text, read it twice

Answer (score 0):

[image]
I started a hex editor quite a while back that I haven't had time to finish, but there is quite a bit done if you care to take a look at it, it's on my skydrive here:
[Hexeditor1.zip](http://1drv.ms/1IoVS45)

The main part of what needs to be finished has to do with highlighting a selection and committing changes.